# iOS Setter Getter

Tags: ios, setter, getter, synthesize

I tried to assign a value to recordingStatus - 
ie recordingStatus = 1 
But it doesn't go into the setter which i want some custom code.. what's wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Pier.

In file.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *recordingStatusText;
@property (nonatomic)int recordingStatus;
....
```

In file.m

```
/* -------------------- Property Setter and Getters ----------------------*/
@synthesize recordingStatus;

- (int) getRecordingStatus {
    return recordingStatus;
}

- (void) setRecordingStatus:(int)status 
{
[_recordingStatusText setText: @"Just testing!"];
recordingStatus = status; 
}
```

Comment: FYI: The getter doesn't start with a `get`

Comment: Yeah I just knew that, sorry abt it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set and get your property, you should use `self.property = newValue;`.

**OVERRIDING SETTERS AND GETTERS**

For getters you don't need to write 'get' in the method signature. So, your getter method uses the wrong name. If you want to override it, the method should be

```
-(int) recordingStatus {
    // Custom Getter Method
    return _recordingStatus;
}
```

In the case of `int`s, Objective-c wants to see your setter and getter methods in the format of

```
-(void)setValue:(int)newValue;
-(int)value;
```

Comment: self.property = newValue was it, thanks for the detailed answer, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Can you show the code where you call the setter? I'm assuming you're accessing the ivar directly by doing something like this (assuming your ivar is named recordingStatus):

```
recordingStatus = 1
```

Instead try this:

```
self.recordingStatus = 1
```